# regex how to match specific words and specific delimeters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture some input from the user.

```
            /mon,thu',
            /mon',
            /mon,thu,wed',
            /mon,thu-sun'
            /mon,tue-thu,sun'
```

so the "business logic" is that the user can put any of the following words

```
mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun
```

and they can either be separated by

```
- or ,
```

if they are separated by

```
-
```

there can only be one day either side i.e

```
mon-wed
```

not

```
mon-wed-sun
```

if separated by a

```
,
```

then only one of the mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun can be either side of it.

Basically
`,` 
represents a specific day and 
`-` 
represents a range of days

the closest I have been able to get is:

```
(\bmon\b|\btue\b|\bwed\b|\bthu\b|\bfri\b|\bsat\b|\bsun\b)
```

Comment: What makes you think a regex by itself is the right tool for this problem?

Comment: What regex engine (language/tool) are you using?

Comment: im writing the logic in python to read aws rds tags. I'm not sure if regex is the best solution for the problem but it seemed a good place to start. Wow lots of amazing answers thanks, guys! On reflection, I think there is too much logic to try and put into a regular expression. This problem might be better suited by breaking down the data and then applying rules to each small piece

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this:

```
(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(, ?(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))*(- ?(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?(, ?(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))*
```

The idea here is that it matches day(,day)*(-day)?(,day)*

It matches the following:

```
mon,thu
mon
mon,thu,wed
mon,thu-sun
mon,tue-thu,sun
mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun (even with spaces in ,)
mon-wed
```

but not:

```
mon-wed-sun
```

Comment: I don't think you should have `^` and `$` in the regexp. His days aren't at the beginning or end of the line.

Comment: good try! but why all the unneeded capture groups its hurting my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue. basically, matching "mon" to "sun" then an optional comma not followed by a - `(?:,(?!-))?`, followed by a repeating (0 to 1) `-(mon to sun)`.
when the case of `mon-sun` the optional comma will fail the match, hence it 
will skip, allowing the `-` to succeed.

```js
const logicalRE = /(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?:,(?!-))??(?:-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)){0,1}/g;


/* cases */
const tCases = ["mon,thu", "mon", "mon,thu,wed", "mon,thu-sun", "mon,tue-thu,sun", "mon-wed-sun", "mon,-thu"]


tCases.forEach(tCase => {
    console.log(tCase.match(logicalRE))
})
```

demo link: https://regex101.com/r/BcqUye/5

Comment: Your regexp matches `tue-thu-fri`

Comment: @Barmar ahh, it was not added to the cases so i didnt account for it, its fixed now.

Comment: It also matches `mon,-thu`

Comment: @Barmar haha.. added to the test case and fixed the regex!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PCRE pattern (or any other regex dialect that supports defines) you might wan't to avoid repeating the weekdays over and over, e.g. using

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<weekday>\b(?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)\b)
  (?<field>(?&weekday)(?:-(?&weekday))?)
)
(?&field)(?:,(?&field))*
```

in verbose mode. See https://regex101.com/r/ELPd6V/1

Note that this would profit from cleaning up the mess around it first and then applying anchors, currently `mon-tue-wed` will give you two matches.